# Removing alpha channel from ListView ConvertView

Tags: android, listview

I am using a `ListView` with my own `BaseAdapter` to render a list of items. It is possible to highlist an item. When I do that, I set the background in the `BaseAdapter` like this:

```
if (position == selectedItem) {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mylightcyan);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(0);
}
```

This works very well, except that the `View`s inside the `convertView` (there are some buttons to edit the item) seem to be a little transparent, even though `getAlpha()` returns `1.0`.

When I explicitly set the background of the contained `Button`, it renders hoe I want it. How can I "remove" this alpha-like behaviour?

What I get:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: it is possible to have your getView() method from adapter? please post it with the xml layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the *.9.png files android uses as the default resource for buttons have transparency to them (the buttons themselves are semi-transparent). Therefore, setting the alpha to 0 would only make it as opaque as the original image themselves.

One way (though tedius) would be to make custom drawables/xmls of every style (button, switch, etc) in the list, and include those in your project.

Instead, you can do something hacky: wrap each of your elements of your BaseAdapter (ie. buttons, switches, etc) in a linearlayout, and set the background of those linearlayouts to the same background in your list. This way, you will have an opaque background directly behind your buttons that will mask the highlight color.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept even though I choose another way to fix it. I just put an `ImageView` in the line to denote the activation of it.